# Webkit adds extra padding and Firefox does not

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

The below HTML and CSS render differently on Webkit and Firefox. Webkit shows an extra 1-2 pixels of padding between the top of the text and the border.

```
<div id="R">HELLO WORLD</div>

#R {
  border: thin solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p0wh01p4/21/

Where does it come from and how does one fix it?

Edit: below is a semi-transparent Firefox screenshot superpositioned over a Chrome screenshot to show the difference. Vertically they are lined up and horizontally they are shifted slightly relative to each other.

[image]

Comment: Probably the browsers have a different calcuation for `line-height`

Comment: I don't see much difference in metrics. [Side by side screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH0Q3.png). You may need to zoom in to confirm that the vertical lines are all in the same position. Even if, ahem, the two browsers use different display fonts!

Comment: @Paulie_D With a specific `line-height: 1` in the css? I've never seen that happen. With fractional pixels for heights, sure, but never in cases like this.

Comment: @MrLister I updated the post with a screenshot